# AWK compare two rows by specific column and print uniqely by split

Tags: awk, split, compare

I would like to compare specific column ($3) of two rows in sorted file. If there is match split $5th column and $10 to $100 columns by ','. If there is not ',', print everytime same value. For first matched row print before comma and for second match print after comma.

Input:

```
chr6 113 1 A C ......
chr6 123 2 C G,T ....
chr6 123 2 C G,T .....
```

Ouptput:

```
chr6 113 1 A C ......
chr6 123 2 C G ....
chr6 123 2 C T .....
```

I tried somtethin like this:

```
for (key in matches) {
        split(matches[key], values, " ");
        count = length(values);
        if (count > 1) {
            for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                print key OFS values[i];
            }
        } else {
            print key OFS matches[key];
```

Comment: for starters, lines 2 and 3 can be combined into ::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::: ::::::::: ::::::::::::: :::::::::::: ::::::::: ::  `count = split(matches[key], values, " ");` ::::: ::::::::: you can further streamline with the next statement  `if (1 < ( count = split(matches[key], values, " "))) { … }`

Comment: You write "_split ($10 to $100) columns_" but your example splits starting at column 5. Is it an error? And what happens when you have not two consecutive rows with same third field but 3 or more? Please answer by editing your question, not in comments.

Comment: in the sample what does `....` mean? is this the 'rest of the line' that we're supposed to leave as is? are these additional columns (how many) that need to be split? please update the question with these additional details

Comment: the current `awk` script is incomplete (eg, how is the `matches[]` array populated?);   please update the question with your complete `awk` script

Answer (score 1):

If:

- you never have more than two consecutive lines with same third field,
- fields 10 to 100 all look like `X` or `X,Y` where `X` and `Y` are words that do not contain spaces or commas,
- you want to print non-matching lines unmodified,

you could try something like:

```
function print_prev() {
  if(mode == 0) { print prev; return }
  n = split(prev, a)
  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if(i>=10 && i<=100) { m = split(a[i],b,/,/); a[i] = b[m < mode ? m : mode] }
      printf("%s%s", a[i], (i == n) ? "\n" : OFS)
    }
}

NR > 1 && $3 == prev3 { mode = 1; print_prev(); mode = 2 }
NR > 1 && $3 != prev3 { print_prev(); mode = 0 }
{ prev3 = $3; prev = $0 }
END { print_prev() }
```

The `print_prev` function prints the previous row (`prev`) in one of 3 forms:

- mode 0 (or undefined): print unmodified
- mode 1: print fields 1-9, left half of fields 10-100, fields 101-NF
- mode 2: print fields 1-9, right half of fields 10-100, fields 101-NF, or entire field if it dos not contain a comma

Answer (score 1):

A two-pass approach.

First pass finds candidates. Second pass alters them.

To avoid storing two counters, I've been a bit tricky with counting candidates. After the first pass, 1 means unique, 3 means seen twice.

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { n[$3] = 2*n[$3]+1; next }

    n[$3]>3 {
        printf "too many copies (line %d)\n",FNR >"/dev/stderr"
        next
    }

    --n[$3] {
        re = n[$3]==2 ? ",.*" : ".*,"
        for (i=c1; i<=c2; i++) sub(re,"",$i)
    }

    { print }

' c1=10 c2=100 inputfile inputfile >outputfile
```

Comment: why not `n[$3]++` to simply count?

Comment: @karakfa to avoid editing unique lines. With my assignment, `--n[$3]` is zero for unique and non-zero **even after decrement** for non-unique. With `n[$3]++` some other way to keep track is needed (eg. extra counter) since after decrement, it is ambiguous if line is unique or not